# Quadruple Recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I came across the following recurrence for an integer-valued sequence in $k,l,m,n$:
$$f(n+1,k+1,l,m) = f(n,k+1,l-k-1,m)+f(n,k,l,m-n+k).$$
I think a generating function would be a bit cumbersome, and I tried to think of a combinatorial sequence with the same recursion, but haven't come up with anything yet. Any ideas?

A similar sequence $f(n,k,l)$ satisfying
$$f(n+1,k+1,l) = f(n,k+1,l-k-1)+f(n,k,l)$$
counts the number of partitions of $l$ with no part exceeding $k$ and length less than $n-k.$

Comment: The indices that are where the exponent usually stay are a bit confusing . Maybe change $a_{x,y}^{z,t}$ to $f(x,y,z,t)$ ?